# Use soup.get_text() with UTF-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I need to get all the text from a page using BeautifulSoup. At BeautifulSoup's documentation, it showed that you could do `soup.get_text()` to do this. When I tried doing this on reddit.com, I got this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError in soup.py:16
  'cp932' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 2262: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I get errors like that on most of the sites I checked.
I got similar errors when I did `soup.prettify()` too, but I fixed it by changing it to `soup.prettify('UTF-8')`. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks in advance!

**Update June 24**
I've found a bit of code that seems to work for other people, but I still need to use UTF-8 instead of the default. Code:

```
texts = soup.findAll(text=True)

   def visible(element):
      if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']:
         return False
      elif re.match('', str(element)): return False
      elif re.match('\n', str(element)): return False
      return True

   visible_texts = filter(visible, texts)

   print visible_texts
```

Error is different, though. Progress?

```
UnicodeEncodeError in soup.py:29
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbb' in position 1: ordinal not in range
(128)
```

Answer (score 2):

soup.get_text() returns a Unicode string that's why you're getting the error.

You can solve this in a number of ways including setting the encoding at the shell level.

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

You can reload sys and set the encoding by including this in your script.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  reload(sys)
  sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

Or you can encode the string as utf-8 in code. For your reddit problem something like the following would work:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/python"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

print(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: in Python 3.8 I'm getting AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding' but the other solutions seem to work well

Answer (score 0):

You can't do str(text) if you may be dealing with unicode on the page. Instead of str(), use unicode().